# Why does .net load the prod json values when running via visual studio code?

Tags: .net, .net-6.0

I have created a new .net web api project.

There are 2 json settings file - 1 is for dev and other is for prod.

I add key1 to dev json file and add key2 to prod json file.

In my program.cs I have following code:

```
builder.Configuration["key1"]
builder.Configuration["key2"]
```

Even though I have run the project via visual studio code, why is it loading the value from the prod json file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The environment isn't affected by how you run the application. It's determined by checking the `DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT` or `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` environment variables. You can configure your IDE or editor to set those environment variables to a specific value when starting the project but that's no different than opening a console and setting the environment variables.

This is described in [Used multiple environments in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-6.0) but actually applies to any .NET Core application that uses either the Generic host.

Different IDEs use different ways to specify debugging profiles and set environment variables when starting an application.

- In Visual Studio you can specify the environment variables in the Debug Properties page. Those values are stored in the `Properties\launchSettings.json` file. This is described in  [Development and launchsettings.json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-6.0#development-and-launchsettingsjson).
- JetBrains Rider supports both `launchSettings.json` and its own profiles.
- Visual Studio Code on the other hand stores [launch configurations](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging#_launch-configurations) stored in a `launch.json` file in the `.vscode` folder. It can also use `launchSettings.json` by setting an attribute in `launch.json`.

The available attributes are described in [Launch.json attributes](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging#_launchjson-attributes). The `env` attribute allows specifying environment variables.

The article [Configuring launch.json for C# debugging](https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/blob/master/debugger-launchjson.md) describes how to use that file to start the browser, navigate to a specific URL, set environment variables etc:

```
"env": {
    "DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT":"Development"
}
```

The same document shows [how to use `launchSettings.json` in VS Code](https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/blob/master/debugger-launchjson.md#launchsettingsjson-support) by setting the `launchSettingsProfile` attribute.

If you have a `Development` profile in `launchSettings.json`:

```
{
  "profiles": {
    "Development": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "DONTET_ENVIRONMENT":"Development"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You can use it in VS Code by specifying `launchSettingsProfile` in `launch.json` :

```
"launchSettingsProfile": "Development"
```

Answer (score 0):

When project runs, it will pick the values from the `appsettings.json`, and then based on the environment it will pick (and replace) values from the respective env's `appsettings.{env}.json` file.

Following is the internal .NET code that achieves this:

[image]